# CMake variable with limited valid values

Tags: build, cmake

In my CMake based project I have a variable in my CMakeLists.txt that enables what backend to target. The valid values for this variable are limited, say 6.

I want to cache a list of the valid values so that the user can select which feature to enable. CMake should validate the variable.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to validate the allowable values, you'll need to do that yourself in your `CMakeLists.txt` file. You can, however, provide a list of values for CMake to present as a combo box for STRING cache variables in the CMake GUI app (and also an ncurses-based equivalent in ccmake). You do that by setting the STRINGS property of the cache variable. For example:

```
set(trafficLightColors Red Orange Green)
set(trafficLight Green CACHE STRING "Status of something")
set_property(CACHE trafficLight PROPERTY STRINGS ${trafficLightColors})
```

In that example, the CMake GUI would show the `trafficLight` cache variable just like any other string variable, but if the user clicks on it to edit it, instead of a generic text box you'd get a combo box containing the items `Red`, `Orange` and `Green`.

While this isn't 100% robust validation, it does help users enter only valid values if using the GUI. If they are using cmake at the command line though, there's nothing stopping them from setting a cache variable to any value they like. So I'd recommend using the STRINGS cache variable property to help your users, but also do validation. If you've used the pattern of the above example, you will already have list of valid values, so validation should be easy. For example:

```
list(FIND trafficLightColors ${trafficLight} index)
if(index EQUAL -1)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "trafficLight must be one of ${trafficLightColors}")
endif()
```

Or if you're using CMake 3.5 or later:

```
if(NOT trafficLight IN_LIST trafficLightColors)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "trafficLight must be one of ${trafficLightColors}")
endif()
```

Comment: Nice answer! Blog article on the same topic here: https://blog.kitware.com/constraining-values-with-comboboxes-in-cmake-cmake-gui/